# Encrypt connection when using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqlcmd, dbatools, dbachecks

Trying to connect database with an encrypted connection, tried below sql queries:

`sqlcmd -N -E -S tcp:SQLSERVER,1234  -U username -P password -d Database -Q "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,2,2)`

> ERROR: Sqlcmd: The -E and the -U/-P options are mutually exclusive.

`sqlcmd -N -S tcp:SQLSERVER,1234  -U username -P password -d Database -Q "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,2,2)`

> ERROR Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: The target principal name is incorrect. Sqlcmd: Error:
>   Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish
>   connection

`sqlcmd -S tcp:SQLSERVER,1234  -U username -P password -d Database -Q -E -N "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,2,2)`

> Sqlcmd: '-Q': Missing argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734311/mssql-with-ssl-the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The first one failed because the `-E` flag is for Trusted Connections (Windows Auth) and `-U/-P` flags are for SQL Authentication. These are mutually exclusive and cannot be combined.

The third one failed because `-Q` must be followed immediately by the query you wish to execute. In your provided code, you've included other flags between `-Q` and the actual query.

The second one should work syntactically, so you need to investigate the cause of the

> The target principal name is incorrect

error. Take a look at some of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734311/mssql-with-ssl-the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect) and also validate that you can connect via SSMS, or you get the same error in SSMS.